# How to clone special root in a table with tree-like structure in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which has one-to-many relation with itself. Now I want to clone a branch and move it under other root. I mean
[image]

become:
[image]

So far I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID,
                  CODE,
                  NAME,
                  PARENT)
   SELECT MY_TABLE_SEC.NEXTVAL,
          E.CODE,
          E.NAME,
          NVL (NULLIF (E.PARENT, TO_NUMBER ( :OLDPARENT)),
               TO_NUMBER ( :NEWPARENT))
     FROM MY_TABLE E
    WHERE E.ID != :OLDPARENT
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR E.ID = E.PARENT
START WITH E.ID = :OLDPARENT
```

But as you may realized, it only copies the first level and make a double of other levels.
What should I do?

Comment: Please post some sample data and desired result

Comment: @Aleksej Added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID,
                  CODE,
                  NAME,
                  PARENT)
SELECT NEW_ID, CODE, NAME, NVL(PRIOR NEW_ID, :NEWPARENT) 
FROM (
  SELECT A.*, MY_TABLE_SEC.NEXTVAL NEW_ID 
  FROM MY_TABLE A 
  START WITH PARENT=:OLDPARENT 
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR ID = PARENT
) A
START WITH PARENT=:OLDPARENT 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR ID = PARENT
```

**Edited**:
I add one more level to prevent error "sequence not allowed here"

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID,
                  CODE,
                  NAME,
                  PARENT)
SELECT NEW_ID, CODE, NAME, NVL(PRIOR NEW_ID, :NEWPARENT) 
FROM (
  SELECT A.*, MY_TABLE_SEC.NEXTVAL NEW_ID
  FROM 
    (
      SELECT A.* 
      FROM MY_TABLE A 
      START WITH PARENT=:OLDPARENT 
      CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR ID = PARENT
    )
) A
START WITH PARENT=:OLDPARENT 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR ID = PARENT
```

Comment: I can't understand the point of your answer, mind to explain?

Comment: Inner query returns nodes from branch with new IDs, outer query returns new parent ID for them

Comment: Got : ORA-02287: sequence number not allowed here

Comment: Although it still not working, overall idea works. Thanks.

Comment: What Oracle version do you have? What error message do you get?